# Efficiently tracking identical rows of a numeric pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large `DataFrame` with a few thousand columns and up to hundreds of thousands of rows. I would like to drop duplicate rows but also keep track of which rows of the original `DataFrame` were identical before I dropped duplicates.

The `DataFrame` `df` contains only integer values.

One idea is to create a row-hash `Series` to keep track of identical rows with
`hashes = df.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)`
before doing `df.drop_duplicates()`,
or even better `df.loc[~hashes.duplicated()]`.

Since my data is numerical, a faster alternative to proper hashing could be multiplying `df` by a random vector with `hashes = df.dot(numpy.random.rand(df.shape[1]))`. But that's about as far as I got.

I had some stupid ideas like doing a `groupby` using all columns and getting whatever I need from that `DataFrameGroupBy` object which needless to say is a complete dead-end.

So my question is whether there are any nicer and more efficient solutions. The dot product method isn't too bad, but surely there's something better than this hack. I wish there was something like `df.duplicated()` that instead of telling me if a row is a duplicate would tell me *what* a row is a duplicate of, for example by returning a `Series` with incrementing integers for rows first seen and re-using past numbers for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do this. You can use the pandas index functions to get the non-unique indexer for all the values. This returns the index of the values in order.

```
In [11]: pd.set_option('max_row',10)

In [12]: s = Series(np.random.randint(0,10,size=100))

In [13]: s
Out[13]: 
0     7
1     0
2     0
3     8
4     9
     ..
95    5
96    9
97    5
98    5
99    4
dtype: int64
```

This reorders the index so that the duplicates are grouped according to the index.

```
In [14]: x, y = pd.Index(s.values).get_indexer_non_unique(s.unique())

In [15]: s.take(x)
Out[15]: 
0     7
6     7
20    7
24    7
28    7
     ..
22    4
32    4
54    4
76    4
99    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want to do this for a Series but for a DataFrame. The index elements therefore would be multiple thousand long arrays. I still tried to port the idea but can't do `get_indexer_non_unique()` without a `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`.

Comment: pls put up an example then.